# Using Python to do a VLOOKUP within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains the list of employees with their managers. The dataframe has the below columns

Employee ID
Employee Name
Manager Name

I want to insert a fourth column in the dataframe to pull out the Employee ID of the Manager. In Excel, I would have done that by using a Vlookup for the Manager Name in the Employee Name section and pulling out the Employee ID. Can someone please guide me on how this can be done in Python Dataframes?

Comment: "pull out the Employee ID of the Manager" is very vague. Please be precise in what the final output would look like

Comment: Sorry Nicholas. My bad. I also just got the answer to my query through this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291908/excel-vlookup-equivalent-in-pandas). Thanks for offering your help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.